# How to convert decimal to different base-N on MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have two matrix A & B. Matrix A size 1x1013 double and matrix B size 1x12931 double. I want to convert each element of matrix A into base-N from matrix B. For example, first element of matrix A converted into first element of matrix B, second element of matrix A converted into second element of matrix B, and so on.

```
mm = length(A);
nn = length(B);
base = cell(1,mm);
x = zeros(1,mm)
for ff = 1:mm
    ff
    AA=A(ff)
    BB=B(ff)
    x(ff) = str2double(dec2base(int32(AA),int32(BB)));
    base{ff} = x(ff);
end
```

But i got an error.

```
First argument must be an array of integers, 0 <= D <= 2^52.
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You're probably trying to convert a negative number:

```
>> dec2base(-1, 2)
??? Error using ==> dec2base at 24
First argument must be an array of integers, 0 <= D <= 2^52.
```

Check that none of the elements of `A` are negative. If any are negative, then you can do

```
>> x = -10;
>> d = dec2base(abs(x), 2);
>> y = -str2double(d)
y =
    -1010
```

Comment: Negative numbers are not well-defined for bases other than 10. For example for binary numbers it is common to use 2s-complement and **not** the minus sign...

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what "well-defined" means. The binary notation "-1010" is perfectly well-defined (sensu unambiguous) and it represents the number we express in decimal as -10, the additive inverse of decimal 10. There are *alternate* ways of representing -10, such as twos complement (where it would be 11110110). There are good reasons for *computers* to use twos complement (it means that zero has a unique representation, and simplifies addition as a bitwise operation) but there aren't really any good reasons for *humans* to use it when they can just prepend a minus sign instead.